# Is it possible to overlay locations for event triggers from Google Tag Manager/Google Analytics on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am currently trying to visualize some data taken from an event trigger that tracks the number of times my site's users click a link.  In the Events Flow tab, I can see a breakdown for how many times the event has occurred based on country, city or subcontinent.  Is there any functionality built into Google Analytics or Tag Manager that will allow you to plot these locations on a map using the Google Maps API?  Perhaps something similar to the 'Geo' tab under 'Audience'?

Comment: If you do a custom report on your events you can select "map overlay" as an option (this will project a metric on a map depending on the users' location). Is that good enough for you, or does it have to be Google Maps (there is no built-on connection to Google Maps in Analytics) ?

Comment: I believe that the Analytics map overlay should be good.  Thanks for your help!